# htaccess: non-www to www but only when no subdomain is set

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web, apache2

I want this:

domain.tld to www.domain.tld

And other subdomains: sub.domain.tld without redirect to www.sub.domain.tld

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: then he redirect sub.domain.tld to www.domain.tld

Comment: No. This will only redirect if it is `domain.tld` to `www.domain.tld`. Otherwise it won't redirect anything

Comment: you mean my hosting is kidding me?!

Comment: Do you have other rules in your htaccess ?

Comment: oh sorry, fu**** caching. i tried the same subdomain all the time. another subdomain work. thanks!

Comment: i will accept your answer in 5 minutes when its possible to me.

Comment: Cache problems are happening very often. Glad it worked, you're welcome